Is the dual of a principal filter to be a principal ideal?
A filter $F$ on $S$ is principal if
$$
F=\{X\subseteq S\mid X\supseteq X_0\}
$$
for some nonempty $X_0\subseteq S$.
Consider $P(S)$ to be a Boolean ring $(P(S),\cup,\cap)$, then the $dual$ of a filter $F$ is
$$
I=\{S-X\mid X\in F\},
$$
which is actually an ideal of $P(S)$.
Does the terminology prinicpal filter correspond to principal ideal? Actually what does the principal ideal of $P(S)$ look like? I have no intuition about it.
Thanks in advance!

The addition operation for the corresponding Boolean ring is not union, it is symmetric difference (multiplication is given by intersection, though). $P(S)$ with these operations is a ring, and the principal ideals of the ring are exactly the principal ideals of the Boolean algebra, or equivalently the dual ideals to the principal filters.
Observe that the principal ideal generated by $A\subsetneq S$ is just every set of the form $A\cdot B,$ i.e. $A\cap B,$ which are just the subsets of $A,$ whose complements are exactly the supersets of $A^c.$
